# Javascript new date format for current time with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, date, meteor, mobile-development

I have problems with getting `new Date();` to work properly in a mobile app (Cordova/Phonegap). Some suggested that iPhones and Androids requires specific format other then the one used by default by Javascript, like this one: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

Thing is, my app needs to receive from the client its current time (now) and then send it to the server. How can I make `new Date();` so it comes out with mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format? As I see Date() can't accept a format as argument.

Comment: Why not using an external library to do that? Like http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @el_tomato because it seems like a very small task and it worked great on regular web browser. But I see momentjs has a meteor package, I'll check it out, looks interesting and useful, thanks!